# Ext.Net brief introduction along with advantages and disadvantages

Tags: ext.net

I am new to **Ext.Net** can any one guide me what is **Ext.Net** and its advantages, disadvantages why we go for this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any information more over the starvator's answer.

Comment: Yes please  @DaniilVeriga

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. I meant if you have any specific/certain questions, I could try to answer. I think @starvator's answer is a good introduction. Personally, I would say exploring our Examples Explorers is the best way to investigate the worth of Ext.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ext.NET (known as Coolite until November 2010) is a suite of
>   professional ASP.NET AJAX Web Controls which includes the Sencha ExtJS
>   JavaScript Framework.
>   [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext.NET)

Take a look at their [examples](http://examples.ext.net/) and you will see that ext.net provides a quicker way to develop web apps.

> WHAT is Ext.NET?
>
> Ext.NET is an advanced ASP.NET (WebForms + MVC) component framework
>   integrating the cross-browser Sencha Ext JS JavaScript Library.
>
> WHO is it for?
>
> If you are looking to build a rich, modern web application with
>   cutting edge web technologies, unparalleled cross-browser
>   compatibility and an advanced MVC architecture then Ext.NET is for
>   you!
>
> WHY should you use it?
>
> Ext.NET is built for developers, by developers. We provide hundreds of
>   Demos in our Examples Explorer. Need a little support? Check out our
>   Developer Bundles.
>   [Source](http://www.ext.net/)